# Can't call function outside of this Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I tried so many ways to get this code to work and failed every time. I know that it is easy but I can't get behind it...

If I click the 3 Stripes, they will transform to an X - that works perfect... but if I want to click the Menu text - the 3 stripes won't transform.

here is the working Code HTML, CSS and JS

```js
function openCloseMenu(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  $('.navigation-menu').toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

```css
.menu-container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: right;
}

.menu-block {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
}

.menu-block p {
  font: 1.55em "Amatic Regular";
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  color: #53b1c2;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  background-color: #2ba4b8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.bar1 {
  width: 1em;
  height: 5px;
}

.bar2 {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 5px;
}

.bar3 {
  width: 2em;
  height: 5px;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  width: 2em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<span class="menu-block">
    <div class="menu-container" onclick="openCloseMenu(this);">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>``
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="hidden-xs" onclick="openCloseMenu(this);">MENÜ</p>
    </span>
```

Comment: You have one line of code that toggles a class using the standard DOM and another line that does it with JQuery. That's odd enough, but I don't see you even referencing JQuery. Have you done that?

Comment: @ScottMarcus probably because jquery's method works on collection of items too but the standard DOM method works on one element, or the OP is still learning ;)

Comment: You don't have a class called `hidden`, so that will be a problem for your `toggleClass` code.

Comment: @niceman I know, but a JQuery object can hold just one item in its collection, so using both versions doesn't make sense. We need to know what the OP intended, not guess.

Comment: thanks to all answers! yes, im still learning - also one of my first attempts to create a function :)

Comment: ive created a hidden class, but i forgot to add it to the question-code :/ sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Beacause , in your function you send this as a param (this), and in the menu `this` refer to the menu itself so , it wont work ,

Remove param as shown in bellow snippet  :

```js
function openCloseMenu() {
  $(".menu-container").toggleClass("change");
  $('.navigation-menu').toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

```css
.menu-container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: right;
}

.menu-block {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
}

.menu-block p {
  font: 1.55em "Amatic Regular";
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  color: #53b1c2;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  background-color: #2ba4b8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.bar1 {
  width: 1em;
  height: 5px;
}

.bar2 {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 5px;
}

.bar3 {
  width: 2em;
  height: 5px;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  width: 2em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="menu-block">
    <div class="menu-container" onclick="openCloseMenu();">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="hidden-xs" onclick="openCloseMenu();">MENÜ</p>
</span>
```

Comment: You're welocme :)

Answer (score 1):

You may understand your own code:

```
function openCloseMenu(element) {
```

a function wich takes a parameter *element* ( x is not really a good name)

```
element.classList.toggle("change");
```

and then toggles a change on this certain element. So:

```
<p class="hidden-xs" onclick="openCloseMenu(this);">MENÜ</p>
```

This will trigger a change on the menu name. Which we dont want.

---

We want to change this element:

```
<div id="menu-icon" class="menu-container" onclick="openCloseMenu();">
```

Ive assigned an id to it. So we can get it like this:

```
$("#menu-icon")
```

The full code:

```
function openCloseMenu() {//no param needed here
        $("#menu-icon").toggleClass("change");
        $('.navigation-menu').toggleClass('hidden');
 }
```

This answer uses http://jQuery.org. No Jquery:

```
function openCloseMenu() {//no param needed here
        document.getElementById("menu-icon").classList.toggle("change");
        document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-menu')[0].classList.toggle('hidden');
 }
```